# Redirect to success page after return attachment response

Tags: python, django

I want to redirect to success page after django serve download file by response. 
What I have to do?

File is generated by django every time that user request so It doesn't have real file in directory.

"content" variable is just string in .ical format.

```py
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadText(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = convert2calendar(form.cleaned_data['regHtml'])
            open_day = form.cleaned_data['open_date_semester']
            end_day = form.cleaned_data['end_date_semester']

            content = create_ical_download(open_day, end_day, data)

            response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/ics')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="export.ics"'
            response.write(content)
            return response
    else:
        form = UploadText()
    return render(request, 'genclass/index.html', {'form': form})
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Something along the lines of `return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)` at the end of the "valid" code block should do it.

Comment: That can't work, because OP is already returning the attachment as the response. There is no way to do this; you can't return two responses.

Comment: Ok, so Do you have anything that can use instead this way to serve download file without return response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it by redirecting on the client side!

JS Code

```
document.getElementById('link-with-redirect').addEventListener('click', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Should be triggered after download started
    document.location.href='{% url "redirect_destination" %}';
  });
 }, false);
```

HTML code

```
<a href="{% url 'file_to_download' %}" id="link-with-redirect">Click here to download Django 1.9</a>
```

Comment: This redirects immediately after clicking the link instead of after successful download. That's how I understood the question.